Docker authz plugin issue
I am trying to build custom authorization for docker.
I have developed python flask app
@plug.route("/AuthZPlugin.AuthZReq", methods=["POST"])
def req():
  res=json.loads(request.data)
  response={"Allow":True}
  if search(r'/(exec)$', res["RequestUri"]) != None:
    dd=json.loads(base64.b64decode(res["RequestBody"])

Works fine when any user is trying to do ->
docker exec -it container 

Error response from daemon: authorization denied by plugin
Issue:
Want to bypass for some user.
User Field in RequestBody - {"User":"","Privileged":false,"Tty":true,"AttachStdin":true,"AttachStderr":true,"AttachStdout":true,"Detach":false,"DetachKeys":"","Env":null,"WorkingDir":"","Cmd":["bash"]}
is always empty.
How to get local linux user.


How to get local linux user.

That doesn't seem to be possible.
The documentation for auth* plugins notes:

If TLS is enabled in the Docker daemon, the default user authorization flow extracts the user details from the certificate subject name. That is, the User field is set to the client certificate subject common name, and the AuthenticationMethod field is set to TLS.

If you're using the /var/lib/docker.sock Unix socket to access the Docker daemon, "who is the caller" is a datum that doesn't really exist (see Is there a way to get the uid of the other end of a unix socket connection, but the getsockopt(SO_PEERCRED) option would need to be implemented in the Docker daemon itself).  Similarly, it's possible to access Docker via an unencrypted HTTP socket, and (if your machine isn't instantly compromised this way) this transport just doesn't contain the calling user identity.  Docker-over-ssh is another transport option, and again you may not know much about the caller other than their ssh public key.
Also note that, in this call the User is passed as a top-level field; you should look at res['User'].  res['RequestBody']['User'] is the user ID included in the "exec" request, which is to say, the caller-provided docker exec -u option.

Thanks a lot for explaining each  step.
